# How to Apply Transparent Background Color to Division Without Using Opacity Property

Tags: html, css, transparency, opacity

As you know CSS Opacity Property is making transparent background color or image. You can see samples below difference between opacity property, background-color:rgba and blend-mode properties.

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

#sample1 {
  background-color: rgb(221,51,85);
  opacity:0.4;
}

#sample2 {
  background-color:rgba(221,51,85,0.4);
}

#sample3 {
  background-color:rgb(221,51,85);
}

#sample4 {
  background-image: url(https://static.seattletimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/MattDay_Web-100x100.jpg);
  background-color: rgba(221,51,85);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  color:#fff;
}

div h3 {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id='sample1'>
  <h3>Sample 1</h3>
    <p>I'm NOT Original Color</p>
</div>

<div id='sample2'>
  <h3>Sample 2</h3>
  <p>I'm NOT Original Color</p>
</div>

<div id='sample3'>
  <h3>Sample 3</h3>
  <p>I'm Original Color</p>
</div>

<div id='sample4'>
  <h4>Sample 4</h4>
  <p>I'm Original Color</p>
</div>
```

In first sample opacity applies all elements in the div. 
In second sample opacity only applies background color. 
In third sample, using the original color in background color.
In fourth sample, blend-mode applies background-image not background-color

How can I transparent background without using opacity or rgba and also it shouldn't lost the original color.

**Sample transparency usage without losing the original color;**
[image]

**EDIT**

I also add a new sample to the snippet sample 4. It uses blend-mode property, I can apply the image only.

Comment: javascript i think..and in this example i'm not sure the transparency was because CSS but because photoshop..

Comment: background: transparent;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `mix-blend-mode` property.

You can read more about it and its compatibility with different browsers in [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode). Here's an example (tested on Chrome):

```css
div {
  background-color: #d35;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 40px;
}

img {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcThfH4SD1Kod8gzTIO0WtldPqlDacHt2NLm5itWUPf7AHdbo9_2Dg" />
```

Comment: It looks like cheat :) but it can work **in few samples**!. I have a background image in my body tag on the web site and header section should be transparent without losing the original color. **So there is no image tag in my code.**

Comment: It should work in your case too. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/xus6j2cx

Answer (score 0):

```css
.solid {
background-image: url('http://res.cloudinary.com/sayob/image/upload/v1511882466/cat300x200_dq2ewf.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 637px;
height: 306px;
z-index:1;
}
.transparent {
background-image: url('http://res.cloudinary.com/sayob/image/upload/v1527678168/Untitled3_vsdneg.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
left: 90px;
}
```

```html
<div class="solid">
  <div class="transparent"></div>
</div>
```